# How do you prove the area under a null function is finite

Tags: calculus

How do you prove the area under a null function is finite

Comment: What do you mean by "null function"?

Answer (score 1):

If by null function you mean [this](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NullFunction.html), then it is true by the definition of the null function. The area under it over any interval is 0 by definition.

Comment: Sorry I meant a function such as 1/x.  ie it is nonnegative and decreasing

Comment: Sorry I meant a function such as 1/x.  ie it is nonnegative and decreasing